# bitarray.to01() doesn't return only 0s and 1s in string (Python)

Tags: python, string, hex, bitarray

I use the library `bitarray` to manage my bits conversion and to write a binary file in Python. The bitarray.to01() before writing to file is of length `4807100171`. For some reason I can't make sense of, after getting the bits fromfile (`b.fromfile(file)`) and then converted to a string of 0s and 1s with `to01()`, there is not only 0s and 1s in my string (`\x00`) and then, when I work with it, I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '0000000000000000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I wonder if there could be a size limit for the string coming from a file or some issues as such. If so, I haven't found anything about it...

Edit:

Here's a way to reproduce the problem:

```
import re
from bitarray import bitarray 

b = bitarray(4807100171)
b.setall(False) 

if re.match("^[\d]+$", b.to01()):
    print "there is only digits in this string."
else:
    print "there is not only digits in this string."
```

** Edit #2:

However, if I check my machine using `platform.architecture()` and `sys.maxint`, I get this:

```
In [1]: import platform, sys
In [5]: platform.architecture(), sys.maxint
Out[5]: (('64bit', ''), 9223372036854775807)
```

So, this is approximately 2^63. How come it truncates at 2^32?
I have 4GB of ram. I get that 2^32*1.16415e-10*8 (since I'm converting it to a string) ~= 4GB... But what about the fact that this is a 64bit machine?

Comment: `\x00` is the string-repsentation of the NUL character in a string.

Comment: You're trying to take the int of `bit_array`, but nowhere in your code do you show where `bit_array` is assigned.

Comment: I just added the line...

Comment: I'm looking into the possibility where there could be some null during the creation. I'll let you know if it happens.

Comment: `NameError: name 'bit_array' is not defined`.  Following the principles of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) makes life much easier.

Comment: That seems suspiciously like a bug in `bitarray`, given that the documentation says `to01` "Return[s] a string containing '0's and '1's"...

Comment: I just added a code sample that might help you try it out.

Comment: I don't have enough memory on this computer to run your test, but I could believe that someone implicitly assumed that no one would use it for anything > 2^32 elements long.  Could you bisect to see if the problem starts at around that size?

Comment: From the [docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/): "On 32bit systems, a bitarray object can contain up to 2^34 elements, that is 16 Gbits (on 64bit machines up to 2^63 elements in theory -- on Python 2.4 only 2^31 elements, see PEP 353 (added in Python 2.5))".  What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Indeed, it returns "only digit" when the bitarray lenght is 2^32. I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ould not have memory on your machine to run the `to01` method on a bitarray that size. The string will use one byte per digit (at least) - and you hae more than 2**32 digits. Since you are not swappign or getting out of memory errors, you may have hit some bug in bitarray --
But...step back!

Why on Earth woul you like a 4 billion digit string of "0" and "1"s? Print your self a Matrix themed racing track??

If you need to convert even a few hundred thousand digits  to 0s and 1s , to look for some pattern, or whatever, you better doing it interactively, converting a few bytes at a time than wathever you are trying there.

Comment: This seemed like an easy way out for a testing program. However, I have to agree with you. I'll look into breaking it into pieces.